# How to obtain assembly name dynamically

Tags: c#, .net-core

I got a class inside a library like this:

```
namespace Foo
{
 public abstract class EventBase
    {
        public string EventSource => Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
        public long Timestamp => DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
        public Guid EventId => Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
 public class ActionRecordable : EventBase
    {
        public string ActionName { get; set; }
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    }
```

But when I use the library in **Bar** solution, the property EventSource I got **Foo** (the namespace of the library instead of the name of the project that is using it).

Is there any way to get the name of the assembly that is being used dynamically?

Comment: Which name do you expect here?

Comment: My advice is to create static constructor  Foo(string assemblyName)  and past assemblyName parametr on StarUp of your application

Comment: Or create extenssion  method  for IServiceCollection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get assembly name by using Reflection like this

```
 string name = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code which brings the name of the assembly at runtime

```cs
string name =  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
string[] values = name.Split(new char[] { ',' });<br>
Console.WriteLine("FullName Assembly:{0}", values[0]);
```